# API object versioning

Tags: api

I'm building an API and I have a question about how to represent objects.

Imagine we have a system with Articles that have a bunch of properties. Some of these properties are complex, for example the Author of the Article refers to another object. We have an URL to fetch all the articles in the system, and another URL to fetch a particular Article.

My first approach to implement this would be to create two representations of the same object Article, because when you request all the articles, it makes sense that you don't retrieve all the information about the Articles, but for example just the title, the date and the name of the author (instead of the whole Author object), excluding other properties like tags, or the content. The idea beneath this is to try to make the response of all the Articles a little bit lighter.

Now I'm going to the client side, and I decide to implement a SDK for Android, for example. So the first step would be to create the objects to store the information that I retrieve from the API. Now a problem pops up, because I want to define the Article object, but I would need two versions of it and it's not only more difficult to implement, but it's going to be more difficult to use.

So my question is, when defining an API, is it a good practice to have multiple versions of the same object (maybe a light one, and a full one) to save some bandwidth when sending the result of a request but generating a more difficult to use service, or it's not worth it and you should retrieve always the same version of the object, generating heavier responses but making the service easier to use?

Comment: This is a candidate for the Programmers SE

Comment: What do you mean? Did I post my question in the wrong place?

Comment: @aperzroca -- Well, this is more of a general programming question than a specific coding question, but there is some overlap between the two exchanges. It is also a good question :-)

Comment: Ah! Thank you, I did not know Programmers SE :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I work at a company that deals with Articles as well and we also have a REST API to expose the data.

I think you're on the right track, but I'll even take it one step further. These are the potential three calls for large entities in an API:

1. **Index**. For the articles, this would be something like /articles. It just returns a list of article ids. You can add parameters to filter, sort, etc. It's very lightweight and I've found it to be very useful.
2. **Header/Mini/Light version**. These are only the crucial fields that you think will meet the widest variety of use cases. For us, we have a lot of use cases where we might want to display the top 5 articles, and in those cases, only title, author and maybe publication date. Those fields belong in a "header" article, or a "light" article. This is especially useful for AJAX calls as you don't want to return the entire article (for us the object is quite large.)
3. **Full version**. This is the full article. All the text/paragraphs/image references - everything. It's a heavy call to make, but you will be guaranteed to get whatever is available.

Then it just takes discipline to leave the objects the way they are. Ideally users are able to get the version described in (2) to save time over the wire, but if they have to, they go with (3).

I've considered having a dynamic way to return only fields people are interested in, but it would be a lot of implementation. Basically the idea was to let the user go to /article and then show them a sample JSON result. Then the user could click on the fields they wanted returned and get a token. Then they'd pass the token as a parameter to the API and the API would then know which fields to return.

Creates a dynamic schema. Lots of work and I never got around to it, but you can see that if you want to be creative, you can.

Comment: Your proposal makes a lot of sense to me but I'm still wondering if there is a big difference in time/weight of the response so it's worth it to make it the way you propose and put the extra effort in the client-side. I think it should be a big difference, but I have checked the big ones, Twitter and Facebook, and I don't think their API's use different versions of the same object, and there should be a reason for this.

Comment: In regards to Twitter and Facebook ... consider their audience. It's very broad. If your audience is a bit smaller, then it's easier to be more specific with your objects. Also it doesn't hurt to create the calls and if people don't need them, then they don't have to use them. If you're going to make calls with AJAX, I would consider having lighter weight objects.

Comment: Yes, I have considered that, but consider that they have a bunch of traffic and I guess that saving a few kb per response would be a great final saving. In addition, if you consider the whole user session, probably you're going to click and see a few articles, and then you're going to need to make more requests, implying fetching repeated information too. My API is going to be mainly used in a mobile app.

Answer (score 1):

Consider whether your data (for one API client) is changing a lot or not. If it's possible to cache data on the client, that'll improve performance by not contacting the API as much. Otherwise I think it's a good idea to have a light-weight and full-scale object type (or more like two views of the same object type).

In the client you should implement it as one object type (to keep it DRY; Don't Repeat Yourself) with all the properties. When fetching a light-weight object, you only store a few of the properties, the rest being null (or similar “undefined” value for the given property type). It should be possible to determine whether all or only a partial subset of the properties are loaded.

When making API requests in the client on a given model (ie. authors) you should be explicit about whether the light-weight or full-scale object is needed and whether cached data is acceptable. This makes it possible to control the data in the UI layer. For example a list of authors might only need to display a name and a number of articles connected with that author. When displaying the author screen, more properties are needed. Also, if using cached data, you should provide a way for the user to refresh it.

When the app works you can start to implement optimizations like: Don't fetch light-weight data if full-scala data is already known & Don't fetch data at all if a recent cache copy exists. I think the best is to look at the actual use cases and improve performance with the highest value for the user.